# How to define URLs only once for server and client?

Tags: django, angular, server, routes, client

everyone! I am building a web application, i.e. a server-client application. For the interaction between the two, I have to define the URLs twice (hard-coded strings), both on the backend and the frontend, which makes future changes hard, because it would require changing the code in two places, rather than just one.

I am using `Django` and `Angular` and so I am looking for a way to specify the back end endpoints once, then ideally read them and use them for the **Angular production build**. Therefore changes to the endpoints will only require a new build, but no further changes.

Should these be defined in some `.cfg` file and be read by the back end on server startup and maybe somehow add them to the `Angular's build process`? Any suggestion would help because this redundancy comes in almost every webapp project and there has to be a more clever solution!

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8

Answer (score 1):

Here, it is the backend application that owns and defines url mappings to entities. It is possible that multiple clients can consume from the same API, like a web client, an Android client and an iOS client. In this setup, your backend is the point of truth for the url mappings, and client applications should be configured to use the url mappings defined in the backend application.

One possible way to do this is to serve defined urls in the backend on a path of the backend application, and have your client applications configure themselves using the data provided there. For example, if you use Django Rest Framework, by default, on the root path of the API ("/"), resources along with url mappings for the resources are served. You can use such a mechanism to configure your client applications on build time.

Answer (score 1):

How many endpoints and how likely are you to alter them? Most likely you will always have to make more changes than just in 1 place as the reason behind changing an endpoint is normally you are trying to POST or GET new data structures. This would mean you will have to alter that request process anyway to handle the new data type or what was being posted.

Also, consider some of the publicly available api's out there - they don't give you an endpoint that serves a config file of available routes. When they make a change to their endpoints they usually create a versioned api so that consumers can upgrade in their own time.

In my opinion, unless you are planning a large scale web app, I wouldn't be too worried about trying to implement something like this.